# Exhausted ResultSet Issue with Servlet Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Every time I run this code it gives me an exhauset resultset error. Im not sure what Im doing wrong but Ive tried removing the .next(); code for either one or all resultsets and then the error given is the ResultSet next wasnt called.

Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Just curious what people might think the issue could be? Ive done similar earlier in my servlet code but only used 1 statement and then 1 prepared statement. This time Im using 2 statements and 1 prepared statement.

```
String opt1 = req.getParameter("RecName"); //Retrieves info from HTML form
String ingr1 = req.getParameter("Ing1"); //Retrieves info from HTML form

stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt1 = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs11 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT recipe_ID FROM GM_Recipes WHERE rec_name='" + op1 + "'"); //choose recipe_ID from sql table
rs11.next();

ResultSet rs12 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ingredient_ID FROM GM_IngredientDB WHERE ing_name='" + ingr1 + "'"); //choose ingredient_ID from sql table
rs12.next();

int olo = ((Number) rs11.getObject(1).intValue(); //convert resultset value to int
int olo1 = ((Number) rs11.getObject(1).intValue(); //convert resultset value to int

PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO GM_RecLnk(recipe_ID,ingredient_ID) VALUES (?,?)");
pstmt1.clearParameters();

pstmt1.setInt(1,olo);
pstmt1.setInt(2,olo1);

ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
rs1.next();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `executeQuery()` for an insert, instead of [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) or `execute()`? What do you expect the result set to contain after that statement is executed?

Comment: Don't use unparametrized queries because they invite SQL injection.

Comment: The sql injection issue is not a problem. Its an amateur project so thats fine.

Comment: You never check if `ResultSet.next()` returned `true`. Executing a statement again will close the result set produced by a previous execute, so when you do `rs11.getObject` it is **already closed**.

Comment: SQL injection is also (or even more) a problem in hobby projects. Don't teach yourself bad practices.

Comment: I changed to executeUpdate(); But still have the exhausted resultset issue.

Comment: Please update your question, include the exception stacktrace and point out which line produces the error; I'm still convinced it is either (or both) of the problems I indicated in a previous comment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hmm thats interesting. To solve that issue should I place a rs11.close(); after the get object code and after those lines of code do the same on the rs12 resultSet?

Comment: You need to study how JDBC works, eg by following tutorials and reading the API documentation; don't just guess at solutions. Given your current code your idea won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas on your code (in comments)

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt1 = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs11 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT recipe_ID FROM GM_Recipes WHERE rec_name='" + op1 + "'"); //choose recipe_ID from sql table

//Check if you HAVE a line here!
if(!rs11.next()) {
  System.out.println("No Recipe Found");
}

//Use stmt1 - that's why you created it?!    
ResultSet rs12 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT ingredient_ID FROM GM_IngredientDB WHERE ing_name='" + ingr1 + "'"); //choose ingredient_ID from sql table
if(!rs12.next()) {
  System.out.println("No Ingredient Found");
}

int olo = ((Number) rs11.getObject(1).intValue(); //convert resultset value to int
//Read Ingredient from rs12 -> that's where you selected it into
int olo1 = ((Number) rs12.getObject(1).intValue(); //convert resultset value to int
```

While this might point you into the right direction for solving the current issue, you should consider learning about clean code.

Consider this code making use of try-with-resource, refactored out some methods, using prepared statements.

```
   //Replace exiting code
    String opt1 = req.getParameter("RecName"); //Retrieves info from HTML form
    String ingr1 = req.getParameter("Ing1"); //Retrieves info from HTML form

    int recipieId = getRecipeId(con, opt1);
    int ingredientId = getIngredientId(con, ingr1);

    if(recipeId > 0 && ingredientId > 0) {
        //Process result
        insertRecLnk(con, recipeId, ingredientId);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No INSERT");            
    }


//Helper functions

protected int getRecipeId(Connection con, String rec) {
    try(PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT recipe_ID FROM GM_Recipes WHERE rec_name=?")) {
        st.setString(1, rec);
        try(ResultSet rs11 = st.executeQuery()) {
          //choose recipe_ID from sql table                     
            if(rs11.next()) {
              return rs11.getInt(1);  
            }
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("No Recipe Found");
    return -1;
}

protected int getIngredientId(Connection con, String ing) {
    try(PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ingredient_ID FROM GM_IngredientDB WHERE ing_name=?")) {
        st.setString(1, ing);
        try(ResultSet rs11 = st.executeQuery()) {
          //choose recipe_ID from sql table                     
            if(rs11.next()) {
              return rs11.getInt(1);  
            }
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("No Ingredient Found");
    return -1;
}

protected void insertRecLnk(Connection con, int rId, int iId) {
    try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO GM_RecLnk(recipe_ID,ingredient_ID) VALUES (?,?)")) {
        ps.setInt(1, rId);
        ps.setInt(2, iId);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```